# Appcelerator Requesting and using Json file

Tags: json, titanium, appcelerator

I'm learning how to use a third party API called Wunderground and I don't know how to request, receive, and use their results which is in a Json format.
If you see their website a developer can sign up for free and receives an API KEY. You can then request weather data in the following URL format.. http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/FEATURE/[FEATURE…]/[SETTING…]/q/QUERY.FORMAT
So I have tried it in my web browser by typing some parameters and I received a very long Json file with the correct information (I checked). Problem is I don't have the slightest idea of how to create a variable which can make this request, and even if I was able to do that I don't know where should I receive the file and how to get only the results I want (in this case current weather).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) to make request.
For code examples related to Json parsing you can use:

- [Appcelerator: Using JSON to Build a Twitter Client](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/appcelerator-using-json-to-build-a-twitter-client/)
- [HTTPClient()](http://screencasts.org/episodes/iphone-app-javascript-using-titanium)